# Sextante in Qgis 1.9 alpha on Ubuntu can't find saga gis 2.1

Tags: qgis, ubuntu, saga, sextante-qgis-plugin

I am using Qgis 1.9 on Ubuntu 13.04, Sextante is a core part of qgis now. I am trying to access the SAGA 2.1 libraries through qgis and I keep getting a popup window that says SAGA is not installed. I can run SAGA and it works. Normally, I would go into the sextante configuration menu and make sure sextante is looking the right directory (/usr/lib/saga) However, that part of the configuration menu is gone.

I went to the qgis options and checked the environment variables and I do not see one for saga, nor is it listed in the PATH variable. I tried adding in a SAGA path variable with no luck. Does anyone here know how to update or add a system variable to qgis 1.9 alpha so that qgis will know where saga is? The end goal will be the ability to have sextante properly access the saga libraries. Many of my Sextante modeller scripts rely HEAVILY on those libraries. I love qgis 1.9 and would hate to have to go back to 1.8 if i do not have to.

Thanks

EDIT:
I was able to install the nightly version of 1.9 alpha on my windows work terminal using the OSGeo4w installer. I went into the advanced install options and made sure I installed SAGA (2.0.8.3) at the same time. Same problem seems to be happening. Everything seems to be working just fine when. Based on these findings I purged everything off of my Ubuntu laptop and tried again ( this time installing SAGA first). Still my problem persist.

EDIT 2:

I installed the official release of Qgis 2.0.1 from the Ubuntugis unstable PPA today. In this instillation some of the dependencies are dated and can not be used with SAGA gis 2.1. Here is the error message containing the offending package names.

Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 saga : Depends: libgdal1 (>= 1.8.0) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: liblas1 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

The version of `Libgdal1` that gets installed with qgis is 1.7.4 ( something less then 1.8 ) when I try to update these dependencies, it removes half of the dependencies used by qgis effectively removing it.

Comment: upgrade to QGIS 2.0, it solves the bug.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: I think this would be fine as an answer if you had explained the precise bug that was resolved at QGIS 2.0 e.g. include links to a URL describing it and perhaps another link to where QGIS 2.0 could be downloaded.

Comment: @serge OP here, I have upgraded to the official release of Qgis 2.0.1 from the ubuntugis unstable ppa. This does not solve the problem. If fact it has cause a whole new problem. The installation of qgis through ubuntugis removed one of the dependencies needed for saga 2.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that will work for this issue, please go [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/72957/installing-qgis-2-0-and-saga-2-1-on-ubuntu-13-04/73335#73335) if you are having the a similar issue