# Installing qgis 2.0 and saga 2.1 on ubuntu 13.04

Tags: qgis, ubuntu, saga, sextante

I have been trying to get this working for a few weeks now. I am trying to install QGIS Dufor (2.0.1) and Saga GIS from the Unstable branch of the UbuntuGIS PPA. When I attempt to do this I get the following error

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 saga : Depends: libsaga (= 2.0.8+dfsg-4~raring) but 2.1.0-0~raring2 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

It appears that the dependencies have not been updated. When I try to install saga from the Johanvdw/saga-gis ppa i am told that two dependencies are too old and required by QGIS. The only way I can get both programs installed at the same time is to install the QGIS nightly build. When I do things this way Sextante can not seem to locate the saga routines. With the changes in sextante now that it has been added to trunk, there is no longer a field to specify the directory that SAGA resides in. I have a similar topic open [HERE.](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/70587/sextante-in-qgis-1-9-alpha-on-ubuntu-cant-find-saga-gis-2-1) I am out of ideas at this point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So I tried some more things and came up with a solution. I will go over what I did step by step and hopefully this will work for others.

First thing I did was uninstall qgis as completly as I know how

```
sudo apt-get autoremove qgis
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

Then I removed the Ubuntugis-unstable PPA

```
sudo apt-add-repository remove PPA:ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable
```

I went to the qgis website and added the [qgis Dufor](http://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html#ubuntu) deb and deb-src to my software & updates application

deb     http://qgis.org/debian raring main

deb-src http://qgis.org/debian raring main

Next I added the keyserver info by typeing the following commands into  the terminal

```
gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv 47765B75
gpg --export --armor 47765B75 | sudo apt-key add -
```

Once I had everything added to my list of repositories I used the update command

```
sudo apt-get update
```

From here I ran 4 commands to install qgis and saga. I had to do each command separately, whenever I tried to do them all in one go I would get error messages

```
sudo apt-get install python-qgis-common
sudo apt-get install python-qgis
sudo apt-get install qgis
sudo apt-get install saga
```

Once all of this had been completed I was able to run qgis and saga at the same time and sextante was able to find and execute saga modules.

Answer (score 1):

I've updated the ubuntugis ppa - it should now be possible to in stall both qgis and saga (last version) from the ubuntugis ppa.