# How to change SAGA path in QGIS 2.18 Standalone

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, saga

I have installed QGIS 2.18 Standalone (64 Bit) with SAGA GIS (2.1.2) and GRASS GIS 7.
Afterwards I have installed the newest SAGA GIS 3.0.0.

I want to change the SAGA folder in the processing options, but there is no option there anymore (like in older versions and explained in this [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/151912/why-is-saga-from-the-processing-plugin-not-recognised)).

[image]

Is there another way to change the SAGA path in QGIS 2.18?

**EDIT 1:**

Is it right that QGIS 2.18 doesn't support the SAGA GIS 3.0.0 version?

In this [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/152228/15459) it its explained which Saga Algorithm Provider can be used.

**EDIT 2:**

I checked the Advanced Options like in the answer from HDunn. There is no SAGA_FOLDER option as well.

[image]

Comment: i see this too (saga works fine from processing, though - bit i'm using saga 2.1.4) Can you run the algorithms from processing successfully, or do get segmentation fault in the logs? also, can you run saga_cmd ok from the command line?

Comment: The SAGA algorithms work fine from processing. Within the directory `C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\saga` I can run the SAGA (saga_cmd.exe) as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **QGIS 2.18.2** on Windows, SAGA folder option came back again. Yay!
[image]

And SAGA 3.0.0 is now up and running.

[image]

Comment: Is there a QGIS 3 colution for this one? The saga folder option isn't there?

Answer (score 2):

I doubt that there is much use trying to change the path to SAGA 3.0 since there are no SAGA 3.0 algorithm descriptions in Processing yet:

[image]

(screenshot from qgis-dev on 2016-11-04)

SAGA algorithm parameters keep on changing, most likely it's not as simple as renaming an existing folder of descriptions.

Answer (score 1):

In the QGIS advanced options -> processing -> configuration menu, you can access the provider paths that used to be in the processing menu, including SAGA 
[image]

Comment: I tried your advice but there is no option SAGA_FOLDER to change. See my edit above.

Comment: @Stefan what QGIS installation do you have? network? standalone?

Comment: I installed the standalone version.

Comment: @Stefan I've reproduced it, I'll see if there's a solution

Answer (score 0):

I corrected this problem (as far as I can tell) for 2.18.14 by copying the saga folder downloaded via OSGeo [C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\saga] and pasting it into the qgis apps folder C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps. The folder that this version of standalone Qgis was installed with is saga-ltr. You could try renaming saga-ltr to saga, but I do not know if that will work.