# Set QGIS 3.X additional dependencies in Manjaro

Tags: qgis, r, saga, tools, arch-linux

I am running QGIS 3.10 under Manjaro. I would like to add SAGA and R support to my QGIS tools as described in this thread ([Configuring QGIS and SAGA on Ubuntu](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/87485/configuring-qgis-and-saga-on-ubuntu)). The solution described here does not work in my case, however.

I have installed R 3.6.2 and SAGA 7.5.0-2 and activated the latter in the processing options (R does not appear here). However I can't see any SAGA tools in my toolbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone has found a solution with [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/345121/no-saga-available-in-qgis-processing). However, the plugin **qgis-processing-saga-nextgen** has limited compatibility with SAGA GIS 7.5 and in any case, you should change some line of codes in the plugin itself:
`in provider.py you must change REQUIRED_VERSION = '7.2' to REQUIRED_VERSION = '7.5'` 
(please refer to [this link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/346558/5780))

At present, some modules work, some others do not (and I'm still searching the reason why)

And good luck